# How to make boot menu always appear without pressing F11

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader

How do I make boot menu appear without pressing f11 every time? I switch between operating systems like few times a day, which makes it annoying having to press it all the time. I have a MSI motherboard, I tried searching something like 'Always show boot menu', but no success.

Comment: so is it impossible to do this the way I want? to have the boot menu appear automatically?

Comment: Dual Boot requires complete restarts, so no it would not be possible

Comment: If it's UEFI you can consider rEFInd tool. https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ You may need to disable Secure Boot though.

Comment: @Tomek - I made the point in my answer that constant restarts from dual boot could waste quite a bit of valuable time. Automating the switch over (if it succeeds) will not change that,

Comment: With UEFI you can press _Shift_ when activating any of the Windows reboot buttons. From the menu that appears, you can select the next boot item. Dunno about any other OSes you’re using though. // I think rEFInd might actually be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and enter the
following commands:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes
shutdown /r
```

The Windows Boot Menu should be displayed after the reboot.

For easy use, you may create a `.bat` file that contains these
commands, set a desktop shortcut to point to it, and set
its Properties to run in Administrator mode.
To execute it, just double-click the desktop icon.

If the Windows Boot Menu does not contain all the Windows instances
(for example for EFI), a possible solution is to add the other
instances to the Windows Boot Menus of all Windows instances.

See the Microsoft article
[Adding Boot Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries).

Comment: I think OP is referring to the firmware’s boot selection menu, not the Windows Boot Manager menu.

Comment: @DanielB: Windows can boot into BIOS/UEFI by `shutdown /r /fw`, but not into the Boot Menu. A possible solution is to add the other instances to the Windows Boot menu: [Adding Boot Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries). I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dual booting Windows and Linux, the preferred solution seems to be to use the GRUB bootloader with an indefinite timeout, instead of the motherboard's BIOS boot menu.

GRUB will give you the option to boot the Linux system it's from, or any other operating system it can find. And GRUB can be configured to wait forever.

See:

- [Is it possible to completely disable Grub timeout?](https://askubuntu.com/a/242009/246491)
- [How can I add Windows 11 to grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425637/246491)

Comment: Before anyone tries to fix the grammar, yes, "GRUB bootloader" is a bit like "ATM Machine", but I think we want search result hits more than excessively correct grammar