# Force boot menu selection to always show on XPS 15 running Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, dualboot

I have a XPS 15 9510 with an internal SSD running Windows 10 and I also have an external SSD with Windows 10 as well.

I have already changed RAID to AHCI and I am able to switch between the two on restart and both load without issues.

My issue is this is a manual process, I always have to press F12 on restart in order to get to the boot menu selection and pick which disk I want to use.

What I want is to always show that menu (or a boot selection menu, does not have to be the BIOS one) by default without having to press F12 on time.

I already configured the boot order to prioritize the Windows Boot Manager on the first option, but it made no difference, it always loads the preferred disk automatically, which in this case is the internal SSD Windows.

Is there any way to force a boot selection menu by default everytime the laptop is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

To always boot up to the boot menu :

- Run an elevated Command Prompt
- Enter the command:
  `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes`.

To undo the command, run :

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no
```

Comment: I did that on just one disk and then on both disks, it does now show the boot menu by default, but it only shows one option to select from, and the option is the windows version that is currently installed on the respective ssd that is booting up. I cannot find a way to have both Windows options in the same boot menu with just your answer.

Comment: Try using [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (free for personal use with registration) to add the missing menu entry to the default Windows installation.

Comment: When I try to use it it keeps demanding for paid license no matter what I try. I selected the free version, installed it and it immediately requested for license. I can't use it for anything after that.

Comment: seems like it automatically requires a license when the windows is in a domain, something that is not clearly documented anywhere as far as I could see.

Comment: That explains it - domain computers are assumed to be company-owned, so are not personal. There exist [EasyBCD Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/easybcd/), perhaps [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) will work, or maybe [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) free version (but the domain may kill this one also).

Answer (score -1):

You could maybe use [[rEFInd]](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to set a boot menu, I use it for dual booting between Windows and Linux and it works nicely.

Or you could try this suggestion: https://superuser.com/a/1692548/1887739

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).